# does the src of a background image relate to its path from the css or the file its being used in?

Tags: css, path, background, image, src

When you use a background image and set the src are you making that the src from the css file the path or the source from the file that the background image will actually be active in ?

Comment: it's relative to the page you are viewing from, i.e. http://www.domain.com/assets/source.css has a `background: url(images/test.gif);`. When viewing it from http://www.domain.com it will try and reference http://www.domain.com/images/test.gif. It's always best to use ./ or / or an absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `src` attribute in HTML is relative to the rendered document. If you had a file `/index.html` and the img you wanted to inlude was at `/img/1.png`, the attribute would read `src="img/1.png"`.

Likewise, the `url` attribute in CSS is relative to the CSS document. If your CSS file was at `/css/styles.css` the attribute would read `background:url('../img/1.png')`.

Answer (score 0):

the path from the css file is what you should use

Answer (score 0):

Links in a CSS file are always relative to the location of that CSS file. This is desirable, since the CSS may be linked from any subdirectory or even from a different server.